# Tumblr Custom HTML

Tags: tumblr

On Tumblr I want to have a 2 column format. That is, a main column plus a right column for the home page. But on the article page I want only the main column.

How can I edit the standard Tumblr theme to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to display/hide the extra column et resize the main depending on what `window.location` returns.

**EDIT:**

If you prefer not to use jQuery, look at the `{block:IndexPage}` on the [tumblr theme documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)

Comment: Is jQuery the only option ? Is there a custom HTML edit for the article page ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the column you want to hide in a {block:index}{/block:index} and it will only show in the home page, if it still dont work, wrap the column in a div and hide it useing css, like:

```
{block:permalinkpage}
.your-wrap {display:none;}
{/block:permalinkpage}
```